# sql function how to return a string based on the condition of a value in the table

Tags: sql

I have this SQL table Invoice. What I'm trying to achieve is to write a function that you send a primary key value to to get  a particular invoice. Then I want to check a field of the Invoice 'Received' This is a bit field. If is 1 I want to return from the function 'Received'. If it is 0 I want to return 'Not Received'.

I had a go at it myself:

```
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.InvoiceStatus(@InvoiceId INT)
RETURNS VARCHAR
BEGIN
declare @Status varchar(100)

    SELECT * 
      FROM [Invoices_Prod].[dbo].[Invoice]
      Where InvoiceId = @InvoiceId

      ...

      How to check the received value?

      ...

    return @Status

END
GO
```

So I'm passing the InvoiceId in and getting a particular Invoice with the select statement. What I'm missing is how to checked the Received field and set the status value to be returned.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [CASE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx).

```
Select [foo], [bar],
  case when [received] = 1 
    then 'Received'
    else 'Not received'
  end as Status
From [Invoice]
Where [InvoiceId] = @InvoiceId
....
```

I do, however, recommend to keep this kind of presentation-layer-logic **out** of your UDF's and even completely far away from the entire data-layer/RDBMS and thus handle the presentation where it's supposed to be done: in the presentation-layer/logic.